# TinyMCE is not selecting elements in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have written a plugin for TinyMCE that will replace itself with content generated from its attributes.  This is working fine in Chrome and FF, however it not working in IE11.

When I process the document to find the custom tag and replace it with the generated content, I use `editor.selection.select(element)`.  This fails to select the element in IE11.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpstoxin/bsz69zcv/1/

Code Excerpt

```
            tinymce.each(editor.dom.select(tagName, node), function(element) {
                if (element.parentNode) {
                    editor.selection.select(element);
                    editor.selection.setContent(element.getAttribute('data-contents'));
                }
            });
```

Since the element is not getting selected, the content is being inserted into the top of the document instead of replacing my custom tag.

Is this a bug with TinyMce, or am I doing something wrong?  Keep in mind, this is a scaled down version of my plugin to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you use the selection in this case try this.

```
    tinymce.each(editor.dom.select(tagName, node), function(element) {
      if (element.parentNode) {
          // BUG: For some reason, this is failing in IE 11
          var dataContent = element.getAttribute('data-contents');
          element.outerHTML = dataContent.toString();
       }
    });
```

Comment: I have been able to make this method work.  The problem with this approach is that I have to fire all the events (BeforeSetContent, SetContent) manually. This is fine for now, but will be fragile going forward should they change the implementation.